# On page load the parameters in JavaScript sort() is getting undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

```
return collection.sort(function (elem1, elem2) {
  if (elem1.aAction && !elem2.aAction) {
    return -1;
  } else if (!elem1.aAction && elem2.aAction) {
    return 1;
  }else {
    return elem1.createdDateTime - elem2.createDateTime;
  }
});
```

This custom sort filter is calling from onInit of another controller of a tab menu. The data won't sort on page load but it will sort when we switch the tabs. Can anyone help me on this?

Here 'collection' is the array and it is loading in this filter file on page load.

Comment: The given code is insufficient to solve you issue. It will be good if you can include the controller information.

Answer (score 1):

when you load page data get washed(scope values get empty). In other hand while switching tabs data remains as it is.you can call function on page load from where you getting data which you want to sort.with that you will get data immediately after page load.